# JAXB, marshalling sub-class that has the same rootNode name as the superclass

Tags: java, jaxb

Let's say I have this:

```
public class Foo {
  private String value;

  // <snip> getters and setters, constructors etc
}
```

And I also have this:

```
public class Bar extends Foo {
  private String anotherValue;

  // <snip> getters and setters, constructors etc
}
```

I want to be able to marshall this to a `Bar` object:

```
<foo>
  <value>smang</value>
  <anotherValue>wratz</anotherValue>
</foo>
```

I'm not in a position to check right now, but if I change the `@XmlRootNode` name of `Bar` to 'foo' and only pass `Bar.class` to the JAXB marshaller will that work? Do I have to do anything more clever than that?

Comment: I'm not sure. It should be trivial to try it and find out, though.